# SMO exclude columns from generated INSERT scripts

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I've been using code like this to script DATA from tables in a SQLServer Database:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

Scripter scripter = new Scripter();
scripter.Server = server;
scripter.Options.ScriptData = true;
scripter.Options.ScriptSchema = false;
scripter.Options.ToFileOnly = true;

foreach (Table table in tablesList)
{
      scripter.Options.FileName = "filename for table"; 
      scripter.EnumScript(new SqlSmoObject[] { table });
}
```

This generates insert statements like:

```
INSERT [Table1] ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3]) VALUES (1, 1, N'Default')
```

Has anyone found a way to exclude one or more columns from being scripted in that insert statement? 
How about a way to filter the data used to generate those inserts?

Comment: Not pretty, but I'd probably just use a regular expression to remove the names as I find the SMO options a total pain. Replacing "\\(.*\\)\s+VALUES" with "VALUES" would work for example.

Comment: And the values Kev? And you are right, it is not pretty and I don't consider regex as programming. I had to scrap SMO entirely and use another 3rd party DB scripts generator that was much faster anyway.

Comment: I actually misunderstood your question and thought you were looking to remove all the column names and just have the values listed in which case the regex I supplied doesn't do that.